# unstable magnetometer readings

Tags: magnetics, precision, accuracy, magnetometer, variable

I did the magnetic calibration [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=265541.0) on the LSM303DLHC for a field roughly 48 uT. The method seems to have worked in that the `combined bias (b)` values went from thousands to hundreds like the tutorial says they should

The readings are around 48uT indeed, but they vary by +/- 50% upon moving the sensor around. Is this the expected behaviour ?

**From the comments:**

- Calibrated and tested in the same spot.
- Was unable to obtain any better calibration values than those from the second run (meaning the first actual calibration run) - tried running the calibration program again and again but the `combined bias (b)` values from `magneto12` software did not get any closer to 0 (neither did they stay the same).

**LE**

I have read today about elevation and bank angle effects (collectively called tilt) on the magnetometer's axial sensitivities. I'll be diving deeper into it. Don't know if that is my issue indeed

http://www.sensorsmag.com/components/compensating-for-tilt-hard-iron-and-soft-iron-effects

**LE2**

Nope, seems that tilt effect is used for correcting heading readings (yaw angle around the z axis) and after doing the correction the overall field magnitude does not change.
Just tried again calibrating it with some longer wires running from the Arduino to the module - same deal. Perhaps their accuracy is just not as good as their advertised precision is.

Comment: Current-carrying wires near the sensor can disrupt earth's field. Have you done calibration in the same magnetic environment?

Comment: @glen_geek Yes, calibrated and tested in the same spot. Then proceeded to test in other spots as well, including outside.

Comment: @Kellogs: Where did you get your calibration values from? Are they the same as in the linked example? I guess they have to be specific for each **particular sensor/device**.

Comment: Is your question about the unstability of the reading (as the title suggests) or about the absolute calibration (reading != 48µT) as the further content of your post suggests?

Comment: @Curd It is about it being unstable - see the edit below. The values are specific to my device, not copied verbatim from that tutorial.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning: I was only able to reduce the bias once. Further calibration did not get the `combined bias (b)` values any closer to 0.

Comment: If you are using the earth's magnetic field for calibration, then subsequently moving the sensor will cut a different path through that field and dramatically alter the value. Is this what you are experiencing?

Comment: @Andyaka I don't think it should alter the overall sensed value - i.e. `sqrt(sq(Xm_cal) + sq(Ym_cal) + sq(Zm_cal))` - should this not be largely the same on moving the sensor within confined boundaries ?

Comment: Yes that should remain the same.